# Views go off screen in iPad simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator

I have an iPhone app I am working on to make universal for iPhone and iPad.  I've created a second main view and xib file for the iPad version and detect the iPad and set screen size.  Here is my code for that:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){

    CGRect  rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];        

    [window setFrame:rect];

mainNav =  [[iPadMainNavigation alloc] initWithNibName:@"iPadMainNavigation" bundle:nil]; 
}
else{
    mainNav =  [[MainNavigation alloc]  initWithNibName:@"MainNavigation" bundle:nil];

}
```

So far I haven't changed any other views other than the main screen, however when I navigate to other views they are slightly too big and go off screen (top and to the right).  For example, I have grouped table cells that go off the screen to the right and you can't see their ends, or the tab bar on top is only about 2/3 visible.

I've checked to make sure I'm not zoomed in at all.  Can anyone give me any advice on why this might be happening?

Comment: That was it!! My navigation controller was auto-resizing its subviews. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work with struts and springs of your view in the IB.

[image]